# How to remove rows of particular name from Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[covid_case_DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dhhM7.png)

I have this pandas DataFrame in Python which contains covid-19 cases of all states in India at particular date .
Now from this DataFrame I want to remove all those rows in which status is equal to Recovered and Deceased.

In other terms, I only want confirmed cases .
So how can I do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want

```py
dataset = dataset[dataset.Status == "Confirmed"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df = df[df['Status']=='Confirmed']
```